# freeBSD: Atom Text Editor

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, node.js, npm, atom-editor

Per [Atom text editor](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/freebsd.md) build instructions for freeBSD:

```
pkg install node
pkg install npm
pkg install libgnome-keyring
npm config set python /usr/local/bin/python2 -g
```

Then:

```
git clone https://github.com/atom/atom
cd atom
script/build
```

This is on a vbox guest with Guest Additions using FreeBSD-11.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso that runs Gnome 3.18.2. Win 10 host.

When I:

```
script/build
```

I get:

```
  Node: v8.8.1
  Npm:  v5.3.0
  Installing script dependencies
  prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.3.0
  prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds/leveldown-v1.9.0-node-v57-freebsd-x64.tar.gz
  prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ ~/.npm/_prebuilds/https-github.com-level-leveldown-releases-download-v1.9.0-leveldown-v1.9.0-node-v57-freebsd-x64.tar.gz
  prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/level/leveldown/releases/download/v1.9.0/leveldown-v1.9.0-node-v57-freebsd-x64.tar.gz
  prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/level/leveldown/releases/download/v1.9.0/leveldown-v1.9.0-node-v57-freebsd-x64.tar.gz
  prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=8.8.1 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=freebsd)
  In file included from ../deps/leveldb/leveldb-1.20/db/builder.cc:5:
  In file included from ../deps/leveldb/leveldb-1.20/db/builder.h:8:
  In file included from ../deps/leveldb/leveldb-1.20/include/leveldb/status.h:16:
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/string:469:
  /usr/include/c++/v1/__config:73:2: error: "_LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR" is no longer supported.        use _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_ABI_DISABLE_PAIR_TRIVIAL_COPY_CTOR instead
  #error "_LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR" is no longer supported. \
   ^
  1 error generated.
  gmake: *** [deps/leveldb/leveldb.target.mk:150: Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/leveldb-1.20/db/builder.o] Error 1
  gyp ERR! build error 
  gyp ERR! stack Error: `gmake` failed with exit code: 2
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (~/atom/script/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
  gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
  gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
  gyp ERR! System FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE
  gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "~/atom/script/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd ~/atom/script/node_modules/electron-link/node_modules/leveldown
  gyp ERR! node -v v8.8.1
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
  gyp ERR! not ok 
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! leveldown@1.9.0 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the leveldown@1.9.0 install script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     ~/.npm/_logs/2017-11-09T22_00_42_308Z-debug.log
  child_process.js:621
   throw err;
   ^

  Error: Command failed: ~/atom/script/node_modules/.bin/npm --loglevel=error install
  prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.3.0
  prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds/leveldown-v1.9.0-node-v57-freebsd-x64.tar.gz
  prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ ~/.npm/_prebuilds/https-github.com-level-leveldown-releases-download-v1.9.0-leveldown-v1.9.0-node-v57-freebsd-x64.tar.gz
  prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/level/leveldown/releases/download/v1.9.0/leveldown-v1.9.0-node-v57-freebsd-x64.tar.gz
  prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/level/leveldown/releases/download/v1.9.0/leveldown-v1.9.0-node-v57-freebsd-x64.tar.gz
  prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=8.8.1 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=freebsd)
  In file included from ../deps/leveldb/leveldb-1.20/db/builder.cc:5:
  In file included from ../deps/leveldb/leveldb-1.20/db/builder.h:8:
  In file included from ../deps/leveldb/leveldb-1.20/include/leveldb/status.h:16:
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/string:469:
  /usr/include/c++/v1/__config:73:2: error: "_LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR" is no longer supported.        use _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_ABI_DISABLE_PAIR_TRIVIAL_COPY_CTOR instead
  #error "_LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR" is no longer supported. \
   ^
  1 error generated.
  gmake: *** [deps/leveldb/leveldb.target.mk:150: Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/leveldb-1.20/db/builder.o] Error 1
  gyp ERR! build error 
  gyp ERR! stack Error: `gmake` failed with exit code: 2
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (~/atom/script/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
  gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
  gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
  gyp ERR! System FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE
  gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "~/atom/script/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd ~/atom/script/node_modules/electron-link/node_modules/leveldown
  gyp ERR! node -v v8.8.1
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
  gyp ERR! not ok 
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! leveldown@1.9.0 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the leveldown@1.9.0 install script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     ~/.npm/_logs/2017-11-09T22_00_42_308Z-debug.log

   at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:598:13)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:618:13)
at module.exports (~/atom/script/lib/install-script-dependencies.js:9:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (~/atom/script/bootstrap:28:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
```

The error log :

[~/.npm/_logs/2017-11-09T22_00_42_308Z-debug.log](https://hastebin.com/ixumoropor.pl)

I figured I would start at what I imagined as the top and tried:

```
npm install leveldown
```

No luck.

I tried:

```
npm install leveldown --llvm-version=5.0
```

That worked per [Level/leveldown/fails to build on freebsd 11.1 #390](https://github.com/Level/leveldown/issues/390)

However, Atom still doesn't build ... same output. Perhaps this has already been addressed somewhere else but I have not had a chance to see it.

While this wasn't a port a party there is a [port bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=220983) as mentioned at [lovell/sharp/Cannot build for FreeBSD 11, _LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR is no longer supported #873](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/873)

I ran across [atom/atom/Atom fails to build on FreeBSD 11.0 x86_32 #6035](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/6035) but I am not literate enough to parse if the issues are similar enough. I don't see them as explicitly similar enough.

I am imagining that leveldown is the 1st error. Following that imagination I am guessing that leveldb is the next error merely by the order of the output. I haven't stumbled close enough to leveldb yet.

I tried:

```
npm install ~/atom/script leveldown --llvm-version=5.0
```

Still nothing.

```
leveldown-prebuilt
```

Worse. Erred faster.

Is Atom not working to build on freeBSD? Am I following the right path to sort out the errors? I noticed the output refs leveldown v. 1.9.

```
atom/script/package.json
```

says:

```
"leveldown": "^2.0.0",
```

but leveldown seems to be on v. 1.5. I don't see that as making much difference but who am I to say ...?

How do I proceed from here to build and run Atom on freeBSD-11.1?

Thank you for your comments, assistance, and patience.

Comment: Also hoping it will be possible to use atom on FreeBSD. It is in the wanted ports list: https://wiki.freebsd.org/WantedPorts, there is a bounty https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29075473-add-freebsd-support-to-electron and also recent good news: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3797

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by patch in "[Bug 222153 - www/node: detect clang version at run time](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222153)".

Source: "[Bug 220983 - www/node: Incorrectly patching common.gypi](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=220983)":

> Reported:     2017-07-24 23:28 UTC by Randy

> The  ports install for www/node is patching common.gypi which includes the following lines.
>
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:85: /usr/include/c++/v1/__config:73:2: error: "_LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR" is no longer supported. use _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_ABI_DISABLE_PAIR_TRIVIAL_COPY_CTOR instead
>
> #error "_LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR" is no longer supported. \ ^
>
> 1 error generated.

> Max Khon freebsd_committer 2018-01-26 16:47:45 UTC

> Bug 222153 contains the patch that fixes this

Comment: Thanks for making time for a suggestion. I gave a look to see what was what because this hasn't been a priority. What I found was: [We do not state that Atom supports FreeBSD.](https://discuss.atom.io/t/freebsd-support/52029/2) ... Unfortunately, [Electron ... doesn't support FreeBSD](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3797) ... support in Atom is out ... until that changes. But, there's [this post](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3797#issuecomment-389093610) you can find [FreeBSD port](https://github.com/yzgyyang/freebsd-ports-electron) to build/install on FreeBSD

Comment: @rob - When I follow the first link from your comment there is another link to "[Add FreeBSD support to electron #3797](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3797)" - The comment ***there***: "Prash-wghats commented on Oct 12, 2016 - Was able to build electron and VSCode in freebsd11RC1. the build instruction is posted in: [Notes for Building Electron and VSCode in FreeBSD11](https://gist.github.com/prash-wghats/89be1ee069d2acf23c289e9c606616e1)", to which "yonas commented on Dec 26, 2017 - Thanks prash-wghats !! Atom finally runs on FreeBSD" as did "ararslan commented on Dec 26, 2017".

Comment: Thanks for your follow up comment. I deleted/reposted my orig comment to you a couple of times to get the links correct. As I commented earlier, [this post](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3797#issuecomment-389093610) points to this [FreeBSD port](https://github.com/yzgyyang/freebsd-ports-electron) which is  [heavily based on @prash-wghats work](https://github.com/yzgyyang/freebsd-ports-electron#credits) which is derived from the [github acct](https://github.com/prash-wghats/Electron-VSCode-Atom-For-FreeBSD) for the gist you linked to.

Comment: With that in mind I am not clear what you're saying with your second comment. Your comment seems to paraphrase my comment's links but points to a gist that is potentially behind what seems like a more recent attempt at an Electron pull request by [yzgyyang](https://github.com/yzgyyang). Thanks for your time you have spent to make your comments.